# Using ViewBag to Fill Dropdown with Custom Text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, viewbag

I'm using a ViewBag to fill Dropdown like this:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.bolumList = db.SbtBolum.OrderBy(s => s.BolumAd)
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YGKisiBolum.Bolum, new     SelectList(ViewBag.bolumList, "BolumID" , "BolumAd"), "Seçiniz", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now i want to show combined two columns in text field like in SQL:

```
SELECT BolumID As Value, BolumAd+" "+BolumExtra AS Text FROM SbtBolum
```

How can i do this using ViewBag and Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var values = db.SbtBolum.OrderBy(s => s.BolumAd).ToList().Select(s => SelectListItem
{
    Value = s.BolumID.ToString(),
    Text = s.BolumAd + " " + s.BolumExtra,
});
ViewBag.bolumList = values;
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.YGKisiBolum.Bolum, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.bolumList, 
    "Seçiniz", 
    new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

This being said/shown, I would completely recommend against this approach. I would rather use a strongly typed view model for this purpose and get rid of the ViewBag.